# como hacer una peticion http a una api correctamente desde angular?

Tags: angular, api, http

tengo la URL de una API, dicha peso esa url en el navegador con las credenciales (id y token como parametros) y me retorna la respuesta correctamente, pruebo con el Postman y todo bien también, pero cuando hago la peticion desde Angular no me retorna ningun resultado, sin embargo el codigo de la respesta es 200. que estoy haciendo mal? tengo un servicio donde hago la peticion con este código:

```js
 parametros = {
    'id': 'xxxxx', 'token': 'xxxxxxxx'
  }

 
 obtenerData(){
    return this.http.post<any>('urlPagina',this.parametros);
  }
```

y en la componente donde llamo al metodo tengo este código:

```js
 ngOnInit() {

    this.hostlistService.obtenerData().subscribe( respuesta => { console.log("se hizo la llamada")} ) 
 }
```

Cuando me reviso en el navegor, el codigo de la respuesta es 200, y cuando intento ver la respuesta dice " esta solicitud no tiene datos de respuesta disponibles " . Soy nuevo en Angular, no entiendo porque desde el postman y el navegador si me funciona, y desde angular no. alguien puede ayudarme? gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Por qué estas invocando obtenerToken() si la función se llama obtenerData() ?

Comment: Un error de tipeo, ya lo corregí.

Comment: Agrega todo el código del servicio, quiero ver cómo está creado, de favor.

Comment: Haz el console.log de la variable respuesta dentro de la suscripcion.